# How to change the path of just a single routes resource?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

In my routes I have:

```
resources :accounts
```

This produces:

```
    accounts GET    /accounts(.:format)          accounts#index
             POST   /accounts(.:format)          accounts#create
 new_account GET    /accounts/new(.:format)      accounts#new
edit_account GET    /accounts/:id/edit(.:format) accounts#edit
     account GET    /accounts/:id(.:format)      accounts#show
             PUT    /accounts/:id(.:format)      accounts#update
             DELETE /accounts/:id(.:format)      accounts#destroy
```

I'd like to change ONLY the following resource path:

```
 new_account GET    /accounts/new(.:format)      accounts#new
```

to

```
 new_account GET    /register(.:format)      accounts#new
```

Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can match any action in the controller to a specific route.

Just add the line to your routes.rb

```
match "/register" => "accounts#new"
```

Comment: If you want to know more about the routing in Rails, I recommned this: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html

Comment: I lose the `new_account` named helper this way.  Is there a way to get it back?

Comment: Actually, nevermind, it gives me a `register` helper now.  That's nicer :-)

Comment: Hmm, when I `render register_path` if the create fails, it complains with a `missing template` error: `Missing template /register with {:locale=>[:en]`.  Is there a cure for this?

Comment: The problem is the render call is looking for a file that matches the name "register", but it can't find it. Maybe you can try this: render :action => "new"

Comment: @Nathan just to know that if you want the `new_account` helper you have to add the `as` option: `match "/register" => "accounts#new", as: :new_account`

Comment: I tried that but then the URL shows domain/accounts.  @Gerry, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

you try this lines in your `routes.rb`

```
match 'register' => 'accounts#new'
```

Comment: Hi, this is similar to what Daniel offered above.  My problem with this is... when I `render register_path` if the create fails, it complains with a `missing template` error: `Missing template /register with {:locale=>[:en]`.  Is there a cure for this?